# Can you use Fetch as Google to get a page crawled and indexed on a domain you don't control?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot

I love Google Webmaster Fetch as Google to get the page crawled for freshness. Is there a way to do something similar on a domain I don't control?

I can't add the specific domain in Google Webmaster directly. But could choosing "Crawl this URL and its direct links" on a page that has a link to the specific page I want to be fetched (again) do the trick?

Another approach that I suspect may work is to increase attention on social media. E.g. if a link is seeing a lot of attention suddenly on Twitter I'd expect it to be checked again by Googlebot. Is there any research about this out there?

Answer (score 1):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278642/1245190) reminded me of https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

This is probably the best way to do it. Would still be good to see some more insights.